# magento : render external html using magento rendering engine

Tags: magento

I'm a newbie at Magento,
Currently I'm studying the feasibility of a project. What I want to do is to use an external CMS to manage layouts, blocks and menusin magento. Let's take drupal as an example.

I have seen a module that does the same thing called [drupento](http://drupal.org/project/drupento) which integrates drupal and magento. Unfortunately I haven't succeeded to make it work. This module stores the html fragments in the file system and magento renders these blocks.
So what I want to know :

- How to use these features using magento APIs ?
- What are the limits and what can we do and what we can't?

Any idea about that ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to Drupal specifically, but since you asked generically about another CMS, I'll answer to that. Since Magento pages are built out in a modular way, you can absolutely replace chunks of the page with ones generated elsewhere. The general approach would be something like this:

1. Identify a block that you want to generate in the other CMS
2. Use Magento's layout files to remove the old block and render a new block that you specify
3. Create your block and pass any necessary parameters into it
4. Have your block's _toHtml method make a call to the other CMS for content

It's up to you whether you want Magento or the other CMS to cache the block contents, but you should probably only allow one or the other to do so.

Since your block can call arbitrary PHP, you shouldn't have many limitations on the Magento side. You may want to make sure that whatever CMS you use can render single blocks of content, and not just the entire page.

Keep in mind that you probably won't be able to call native functions from the other CMS from within Magento (try using Wordpress' theLoop in Magento, ha!), but rather Magento will consume blocks of content from the other CMS as if it were a service. This is because of the usually mutually exclusive frameworks that each system uses.

Hope that clarifies things a bit!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I want to know. But a little question : How much complicated is making a such integration with third party CMS ?

Comment: It depends on how easily you can get the content out of your 3rd party CMS. The best case scenario would be to be able to just include the content as an external URL using file_get_contents. The worst case would be to need to get the 3rd party CMS to output to some other file format and hack both Magento and that CMS. Difficulty may also depend on how much data you have to integrate between the two. Do you need some kind of user ACL for menus or pages? Stuff like that will be more than a little pain.

Comment: Accessing blocs in drupal is very easy so I think I'll write each product properties into temp file and make magento read it. Guess that will be better for performance. Any way thank you for your help. I'm preparing a POC using both drupal and magento.